# Group of new file created by the webserver is always set to sudo

Tags: linux, permissions, unix, suid

I am running a magento 2 project on Apache 2 Webserver.

There is a logfile folder at var/log

I have set the permission, user and group of the folder to `drwsrwxr-x  2 company www-data` by using `chmod 4775 log`

The user always stays `company`, just like the parent user. But the group is set to `sudo`.

How can I change the log folder to make the group of the files always the same as the group from the parent folder which is `www-data`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had to set the GID with `chmod g+s log`

[More Informations](https://www.howtogeek.com/656646/how-to-use-suid-sgid-and-sticky-bits-on-linux/)